# how to parse Firestore data safely if field data type is changed in Server in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

let say I store a user document in Firestore, each user document has name (string) and age (number) as its field.

I can parse the data from Firestore using `User.fromFirestore()`  below

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  User({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
  });

  factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return User(
      name: data["name"] ?? "",
      age: data["age"] ?? 0,
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see above in `User.fromFirestore` constructor.....

if for example the `name` field is deleted in the server, then my code above can handle it by assigning an empty string using null coalescing operator ( ?? )

but what if the data type of a field is changed accidentally ?

for example, the age should be a number in server, but if the age accidentally become string (let say the age field now has string value "twenty two")  then my app will crash if I use my code above, right?

because `data["age"]` is not null but it is a string now, but my User model requires int for age property.

what should I do to handle this?

it is not limited from number to string actually. it can be from number to Geopoint, to List, to Timestamp etc. I need my Flutter app more fault tolerant when parsing Firestore data into Dart object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the type of data you're getting before doing assigning it to the properties of the `User` object.

So this code block below:

```dart
return User(
      name: data["name"] ?? "",
      age: data["age"] ?? 0,
    );
```

becomes this:

```dart
return User(
  name: data["name"] is String ? data["name"] : "",
  age: data["age"] is int ? data["age"] : 0,
);
```

The code checks for the data type and if it is the type it expects, it gets the data from the `data` Map. And if not it assigns the default value.

And this code also handles situations when the data is `null`. This is because `null` is of type `Null` and so it will fail the type check and the default value will be assigned to the variable.

If you have classes with a lot of properties, you can abstract the logic into helper methods do the type check.

Check out the code below:

```dart
    class User {
      final String name;
      final int age;
    
      User({
        @required this.name,
        @required this.age,
      });
    
      static int getIntOrDefault(dynamic value) {
        return value is int ? value : 0;
      }
    
      static String getStringOrDefault(dynamic value) {
        return value is String ? value : '';
      }
    
      factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
        return User(
          name: getStringOrDefault(data["name"]),
          age: getIntOrDefault(
            data["age"],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: we can also change from `data["name"].runtimeType == String` to be `data["name"]  is String ? true : false` right ? Thanks Victor, I get the idea

Comment: Yep! That's even better. I'm updating my answer to use `is`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just make your types `dynamic` or `String`.

You can easily handle `String`s because all types easily convert into string.

Now for the parsing part, wherever you are trying to use the `age` except for display purposes (i.e., `Text(age.toString())`), you can actually try if parsing is returning a valid number

```
final String age;

...

try {
  int ageInNum = int.parse(age);
  return Text((ageInNum + 3).toString()); // If you are doing this for some reason.
} catch (e) {
  // Handle your code gracefully here so that you disable the operation you are trying to perform
  return Text('Unable to perform action');
}

// If you want to do it in the constructor itself
factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  final data = doc.data() as Map<String, String>; // Change the value type to `String`

  int age = 0; // your default case
  try {
      age = int.parse(data["age"]);
  } catch (_) {}

  return User(
    name: data["name"] ?? "",
    age: age,
  );
}
```

This should work.

Comment: it is not limited from number to string actually. it can be from number to Geopoint, to List, to Timestamp etc. I need my Flutter app more fault tolerant when something bad happened on the server side. my code above is just an example so I can easily explain about it. but Thanks Nisanth :)

Comment: The same scenario would apply to any case. All you need to fetch is `String`s. While using them, use them as `String`s. Need to show a datetime somewhere, just show the string you fetched. If you actually need the original data type, then you should use try catch. Could you give an example where this approach doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: I need to safely parse the data in the class constructor only, like I write above.  could you please rewrite your code maybe so I can use it on my constructor? so I can only write it once. I am confused how to apply your solution to my class constructor